# Most pythonic way to update a dictionary value in a list of same dictionaries?

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
my_list = [{'a':1}, {'a':2}, {'a':3}]
```

I want to convert all the `a` values in the dictionary to floats.
What is the most pythonic way to do so?

Can I do it in a single expression that appears on the right hand side of `my_list =`?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can, but it will get unwieldy:

```
>>> my_list = [{'a':1}, {'a':2}, {'a':3}]
>>> [{k:float(v) if k == 'a' else v for k,v in d.items()} for d in my_list]
[{'a': 1.0}, {'a': 2.0}, {'a': 3.0}]
```

Just use a for-loop. A for-loop is perfectly Pythonic. Striving to cram everything into a single expression *is not what Pythonic means*. In fact, it can often be the opposite of Pythonic.

Comment: Think you should mention that this creates new dictionaries (and list).

Comment: If the dicts in the list contain only the `a` key, there's not need to check if `k == 'a'`, Just do `>>> [{'a': float(d['a'])} for d in my_list]`

Comment: @slackmart yes, I'm assuming that silly situation isn't the case.

Comment: I agree with you about that's a silly situation. Even though I dislike the idea of looping through the dict items. What if each dict has over 1million keys? Your solution will loop till there aren't keys left.

Comment: @slackmart yes, that would be an even *better* reason to use a normal for-loop and to mutate the dictionaries in-place, as I suggested in my answer. Of course, we could make a completely absurd list-comprehension to do something similar, something like `[d.__setitem__('a',float(d['a'])) or d for d in my_list]`